# How to find which serial port is currently used?

Tags: c#, detection, ports

I ve connected my mobile phone to my PC and used this,

```
string[] lPorts = System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames();
```

and the result was an array of port names

```
"COM4"
"COM3"
"COM1"
"COM7"
"COM6"
```

Now,How to find which serial port is currently used/to which port my mobile phone is connected in c#?

Comment: Just saw that you asked for links, if you look in my comment to Filip-fku there's a link that might be useful.

Comment: Are we getting this right? I am assuming you want to programmatically access the serial port of your phone. Is that correct? If so then the link ho provided should get you started. All you will want to do in that case is basically try to start using each of the serial ports as if it was the one that your phone is connected to. If there is an error then your phone is not connected to that port..

Comment: Look at my edit for some "pseudorealish" code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously you will need to know the serial protocol being used to communicate. Just send a known command to each port and check back for the expected response. Ports with no device on them will timeout/throw an IOException.

Or you if you don't want to do this through code you can try the same using HyperTerminal or another serial terminal program.

Try something like following:
(Please note I am writing this from memory and don't guarantee this will compile/that I have the method names 100% right, but it gives the general idea).

```
foreach(string portname in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
{
    // Use your connection settings - own baud rate etc
    SerialPort sp = new SerialPort(portname,4800, Parity.Odd, 8, StopBits.One); 
    try
    {
         sp.Open();
         sp.Write("Your known command to phone");
         Thread.Sleep(500);
         string received = sp.ReadLine();

         if(received == "expected response")
         {
              Console.WriteLine("Phone connected to: " + portname);
              break;
         }
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Phone NOT connected to: " + portname);
    }
    finally
    {
         sp.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's supposed to throw a `TimeoutException` as in the sample on the doc page for `TimeoutException` - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timeoutexception.aspx

Comment: You also want to set the ReadTimeout property (e.g. to 500 ms) as it is by default set to [InfiniteTimeout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readtimeout.aspx).

Comment: @filip-fku can you help me with the code, I am also trying to find on which port GSM Modem is connected, can you help me out with a code snippet, that works,